# Nodemailer is not respecting rateDelta and rateLimit

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I created a pool transport for an email like this:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let poolNewsletterEmail;
let poolGeneralEmail;

exports.createTransporter= function(callback) {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    poolNewsletterEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
        pool: true,
        logger: true,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        rateDelta: 86400000, //24 Hours
        rateLimit: 2, 
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST_NEWSLETTER,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT_NEWSLETTER,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER_NEWSLETTER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD_NEWSLETTER,
        },
    });

    callback()
};

exports.getNewsletterPool = function() {
    return poolNewsletterEmail;
};
```

I consume it like this:

```
const info = await emailTransporter.getNewsletterPool().sendMail(mailOptions).catch(console.error);
```

This is the log

```
$ npm start

> ao-api-server@1.0.0 start C:\ao-api-server
> node index.js

[2020-03-30 08:25:39] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.4.6; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6])
[2020-03-30 08:25:39] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.4.6; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6])
Transportador de email general creado con exito para el email: argentumonline@riseup.net
Transportador de email newsletter creado con exito para el email: aolibre@gmail.com
Conexion a la BD MySQL Exitosa!K[0m
Argentum Online API on Port:- 1337 Started at :- Mon Mar 30 2020 21:25:39 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Logged in Discord as AO Libre BOT#6711!
sendNewsletterEmail: El subject asdasdasdasdasd
Hay que enviar 1905 emails
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: HEN.H2O@LIVE.COM.AR
[2020-03-30 08:25:57] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:25:57] INFO  [#1] Created new pool resource #1
[2020-03-30 08:25:57] DEBUG [#1] Assigned message <e8bc3a91-1131-c41a-7e9f-f887a9f7b217@gmail.com> to #1 (1)
[2020-03-30 08:25:57] DEBUG [8YiRWBx0hR4] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.130.108 [cache miss]
[2020-03-30 08:25:58] INFO  [8YiRWBx0hR4] Secure connection established to 74.125.130.108:465
[2020-03-30 08:25:58] DEBUG [8YiRWBx0hR4] SMTP handshake finished
[2020-03-30 08:25:58] INFO  [8YiRWBx0hR4] User "aolibre@gmail.com" authenticated
[2020-03-30 08:25:58] INFO  [#1] Sending message <e8bc3a91-1131-c41a-7e9f-f887a9f7b217@gmail.com> using #1 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:00] INFO  [8YiRWBx0hR4] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: HEN.H2O@LIVE.COM.AR
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: M@M.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:01] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:26:01] DEBUG [#1] Connection #1 became available
[2020-03-30 08:26:01] DEBUG [#1] Assigned message <65afa327-b754-81e5-361d-243d29673b1a@gmail.com> to #1 (2)
[2020-03-30 08:26:01] INFO  [#1] Sending message <65afa327-b754-81e5-361d-243d29673b1a@gmail.com> using #1 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:02] INFO  [8YiRWBx0hR4] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: M@M.COM
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: SHAI_05@HOTMAIL.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:03] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:26:03] INFO  [#2] Created new pool resource #2
[2020-03-30 08:26:03] DEBUG [#2] Assigned message <b465d175-8518-f64c-4f92-3a6cd2d19d5a@gmail.com> to #2 (1)
[2020-03-30 08:26:03] DEBUG [k1JVRGXrL00] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.130.108 [cache hit]
[2020-03-30 08:26:03] INFO  [k1JVRGXrL00] Secure connection established to 74.125.130.108:465
[2020-03-30 08:26:04] DEBUG [k1JVRGXrL00] SMTP handshake finished
[2020-03-30 08:26:04] INFO  [k1JVRGXrL00] User "aolibre@gmail.com" authenticated
[2020-03-30 08:26:04] INFO  [#2] Sending message <b465d175-8518-f64c-4f92-3a6cd2d19d5a@gmail.com> using #2 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:05] INFO  [k1JVRGXrL00] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: SHAI_05@HOTMAIL.COM
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: NADIE@GMAIL.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] INFO  [#3] Created new pool resource #3
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] DEBUG [#3] Assigned message <f2137568-1317-4927-db2a-717e52681e32@gmail.com> to #3 (1)
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] DEBUG [XCYpzqbxy50] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.130.108 [cache hit]
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] INFO  [XCYpzqbxy50] Secure connection established to 74.125.130.108:465
[2020-03-30 08:26:07] DEBUG [XCYpzqbxy50] SMTP handshake finished
[2020-03-30 08:26:08] INFO  [XCYpzqbxy50] User "aolibre@gmail.com" authenticated
[2020-03-30 08:26:08] INFO  [#3] Sending message <f2137568-1317-4927-db2a-717e52681e32@gmail.com> using #3 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:09] INFO  [XCYpzqbxy50] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: NADIE@GMAIL.COM
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: JOAQUINBACA7@GMAIL.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:10] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:26:10] INFO  [#4] Created new pool resource #4
[2020-03-30 08:26:10] DEBUG [#4] Assigned message <cbd3bc3b-4b8e-dea1-876a-59f7a8b76889@gmail.com> to #4 (1)
[2020-03-30 08:26:10] DEBUG [lNOaT7mPh24] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.130.108 [cache hit]
[2020-03-30 08:26:10] INFO  [lNOaT7mPh24] Secure connection established to 74.125.130.108:465
[2020-03-30 08:26:11] DEBUG [lNOaT7mPh24] SMTP handshake finished
[2020-03-30 08:26:11] INFO  [lNOaT7mPh24] User "aolibre@gmail.com" authenticated
[2020-03-30 08:26:11] INFO  [#4] Sending message <cbd3bc3b-4b8e-dea1-876a-59f7a8b76889@gmail.com> using #4 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:12] INFO  [lNOaT7mPh24] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: JOAQUINBACA7@GMAIL.COM
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: ASIER_OH@HOTMAIL.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:13] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
[2020-03-30 08:26:13] INFO  [#5] Created new pool resource #5
[2020-03-30 08:26:13] DEBUG [#5] Assigned message <9e2696f6-dbc3-860b-0c39-8e66ba8390aa@gmail.com> to #5 (1)
[2020-03-30 08:26:13] DEBUG [2o8gi37T4lw] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.130.108 [cache hit]
[2020-03-30 08:26:14] INFO  [2o8gi37T4lw] Secure connection established to 74.125.130.108:465
[2020-03-30 08:26:14] DEBUG [2o8gi37T4lw] SMTP handshake finished
[2020-03-30 08:26:15] INFO  [2o8gi37T4lw] User "aolibre@gmail.com" authenticated
[2020-03-30 08:26:15] INFO  [#5] Sending message <9e2696f6-dbc3-860b-0c39-8e66ba8390aa@gmail.com> using #5 to <argentumonline@riseup.net>
[2020-03-30 08:26:16] INFO  [2o8gi37T4lw] <45975 bytes encoded mime message (source size 45972 bytes)>
Se envio un email de newsletter a: ASIER_OH@HOTMAIL.COM
Se esta enviando un email de newsletter a: EJEMPLO@EJEMPLO.COM
[2020-03-30 08:26:17] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP (pool)/6.4.6[client:6.4.6]
```

As you can see is weird because is not:

- Respecting the rateDelta and rateLimit params
- And the POOL is creating a new connection even though we didn't reach 100 connections

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/

Any idea of what I am doing wrong??
Is it a bug? I am using the last version "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",

Comment: Have you taken into consideration the `maxConnections` variable for pooled connections? It defaults to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rateLimit and rateDelta are deprecated options and any bugs related to these will not be fixed.

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1120